# Visualforce Email template I used {!relatedTo.owner} showing opportunity owner ID not name

Tags: visualforce, email-template

Hi I have created VF email template and send it through workflow action  but unable to get Opportunity owner name on recipient name. it is showing that person name who edit the record. Then I used {!relatedTo.owner} but it is showing owner ID not name. below is my VF code

```
    <p>Dear {!relatedTo.owner},</p>
    <p>Please be informed {!relatedTo.name} is nearing the stage duration planned timeline of 14 days tomorrow.</p>

    <p>Kindly revert back with you plan for us to have the same updated in Salesforce.</p>

    <p>FYI, appended below is a snapshot of the last few activities related to this opportunity:</p>
```

I need VF email template because I have to pull activity history in this template.
Please help me to pull Opportunity Owner name in this template.

Regards,
Russell

Comment: Hi Experts can you please help me to pull out opportunity owner name in VF email template.

Comment: Yes it will give you only Id. here you need apex controller and VF component help  check this example try to implement and let us know if you face any issue http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/05/visualforce-email-template-with-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

use this formula expression to show opportunity owner name in visualforce email template

```
{!relatedTo.owner.Name}
```